# Loading extensions in firefox via selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, headless, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to load firefox addons into headless firefox with selenium browser in python.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
geckodriver = 'C:\\Gecko\\geckodriver.exe'

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('-headless')


profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/am97bfb5.default-1538379314459')
profile.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False)

profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1")
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_version", 5)
profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", True);
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override","Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; HTC One M9 Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36")
profile.exp="D:/test/XPI/uBlock0@raymondhill.net.xpi"
profile.add_extension(extension=profile.exp)
time.sleep(5)


browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,executable_path=geckodriver, firefox_options=options)
print (profile.path)
browser.get('https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/chrome-headless-test.html')

browser.save_screenshot('D:\\Test\\headless_firefox_test.png')

browser.quit()
```

However after running the code I get the following error:

> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 351, in _addon_details
>       raise AddonFormatError(str(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
>
> AddonFormatError: ("[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp6cn69jiy.uBlock0@raymondhill.net.xpi\\install.rdf'", )

Do you have any ideas? I've been looking in other posts on the website, but haven't found anything that can work for the code.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using latest versions? as far as I remember it was a bug in firefox driver, and they fixed it some time ago

Comment: I am using Firefox Quantum 62.0.2 (64-bit)

Comment: I just installed the latest updates for Firefox, and it is now working. Thanks Kiril!

Answer (score 0):

It should work in a newer Firefox version. Update your Firefox and try again

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Firefox Developer Edition instead of standard Firefox. It worked for me in C#. Hope this solution will help you.
Also, as I can see in your code you lunch Firefox with a particular profile, so the easiest way is to add your extension manually to your profile and then you don't have to do it programmatically